# Run wget in background but still see download status

Tags: windows, command-line, wget, timeout

I am running `wget` in Windows (Vista) Command Prompt as follows:

```
wget -b -o test.MP4 -r -A .MP4 -nH --cut-dirs=3 http://website.com
```

If I remove `-b` I really like that the output showing the download status returns to the prompt, but I have a `timeout` command on the next line that I don't want to wait for:

```
wget -b -o test.MP4 -r -A .MP4 -nH --cut-dirs=3 http://website.com
timeout 1800 /nobreak
```

Is there a way I can start the `timeout` line immediately after the `wget` call but still be able to see the download status from `wget`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try appending '&' to force the terminal to run the wget in the background. Correct me if I'm wrong. This worked for me. I tried to exit out of the prompt by using ctrl+c but the terminal continued to display the download progress.

```
user@blr-lv553:~/psuresh_perforc# wget -O -b  "http://93.174.95.27/get/D9711B1858C8BE7CF2DB8774DA10975B/%28Hindu%20Astrology%20Series%29%20V.P.Goel-Predict%20Effectively%20through%20Yogini%20Dasha-Vani%20Publications%20%282006%29.pdf" & 
[1] 32484

Connecting to 93.174.95.27:80... connected.#
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK#
Length: 27052673 (26M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: '-b'

 1% [>                                                                                                                              ] 398,794      108KB/s  eta 3m 29s 
user@blr-lv553:~/psuresh_perforce$ #
 2% [==>                                                                                                                            ] 805,682      162KB/s  eta 3m 35s ^C
 7% [========>                                                                                                                      ] 2,118,066    427KB/s  eta 98s    ^C
 8% [==========>                                                                                                                    ] 2,394,098    482KB/s  eta 98s    ^C
 9% [===========>                                                                                                                   ] 2,689,530    532KB/s  eta 98s    ^C
11% [=============>                                                                                                                 ] 3,061,666    694KB/s  eta 59s    ^C
user@blr-lv553:~/psuresh_perforce$ ^C#
user@blr-lv553:~/psuresh_perforce$ ^C#
100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 27,052,673   791KB/s   in 87s    

2017-02-20 08:48:35 (304 KB/s) - '-b' saved [27052673/27052673]#

FINISHED --2017-02-20 08:48:35--
Total wall clock time: 1m 27s
Downloaded: 1 files, 26M in 1m 27s (304 KB/s)

[1]+  Exit 4                  wget -O -b 

-Hope this helps#
```